# STM32 USB CDC Virtual COM doesn't work if sscanf is anywhere in code

Tags: serial-port, embedded, usb, stm32

I am currently working on an app for an STM32F4 board, configured as a USB CDC device. The code I currently have is below:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : main.c
  * Description        : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2017 STMicroelectronics International N.V. 
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
  * modification, are permitted, provided that the following conditions are met:
  *
  * 1. Redistribution of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
  *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  * 3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of other 
  *    contributors to this software may be used to endorse or promote products 
  *    derived from this software without specific written permission.
  * 4. This software, including modifications and/or derivative works of this 
  *    software, must execute solely and exclusively on microcontroller or
  *    microprocessor devices manufactured by or for STMicroelectronics.
  * 5. Redistribution and use of this software other than as permitted under 
  *    this license is void and will automatically terminate your rights under 
  *    this license. 
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY STMICROELECTRONICS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
  * AND ANY EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
  * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
  * PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT OF THIRD PARTY INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY
  * RIGHTS ARE DISCLAIMED TO THE FULLEST EXTENT PERMITTED BY LAW. IN NO EVENT 
  * SHALL STMICROELECTRONICS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
  * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, 
  * OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF 
  * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING 
  * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
  * EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void print(char * str){
    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)str, strlen(str));
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      print("hello there\r\n");
      int x;
      char * str = "hello 2\r\n";
      sscanf(str,"%*s %d\r\n",&x);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 72;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
     PC3   ------> I2S2_SD
     PA4   ------> I2S3_WS
     PA5   ------> SPI1_SCK
     PA6   ------> SPI1_MISO
     PA7   ------> SPI1_MOSI
     PB10   ------> I2S2_CK
     PB12   ------> I2S2_WS
     PC7   ------> I2S3_MCK
     PC10   ------> I2S3_CK
     PC12   ------> I2S3_SD
     PB6   ------> I2C1_SCL
     PB9   ------> I2C1_SDA
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_I2C_SPI_GPIO_Port, CS_I2C_SPI_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, LD4_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD5_Pin|LD6_Pin 
                          |Audio_RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CS_I2C_SPI_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CS_I2C_SPI_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CS_I2C_SPI_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE4 PE5 MEMS_INT2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|MEMS_INT2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PDM_OUT_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PDM_OUT_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(PDM_OUT_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : I2S3_WS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2S3_WS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(I2S3_WS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : SPI1_SCK_Pin SPI1_MISO_Pin SPI1_MOSI_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI1_SCK_Pin|SPI1_MISO_Pin|SPI1_MOSI_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : CLK_IN_Pin PB12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CLK_IN_Pin|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD4_Pin LD3_Pin LD5_Pin LD6_Pin 
                           Audio_RST_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD4_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD5_Pin|LD6_Pin 
                          |Audio_RST_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : I2S3_MCK_Pin I2S3_SCK_Pin I2S3_SD_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2S3_MCK_Pin|I2S3_SCK_Pin|I2S3_SD_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_OverCurrent_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_OverCurrent_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_OverCurrent_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : Audio_SCL_Pin Audio_SDA_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Audio_SCL_Pin|Audio_SDA_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/**
  * @}
*/ 

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Without sscanf, it works just fine. I can connect to it using a serial terminal. But when sscanf is anywhere that is reachable, regardless of where, then Windows recognizes it as a Virtual COM device, but nothing can connect to it.

Everything seems to give a different (equally unhelpful) reason as to why: putty tells me "Unable to configure serial port", and a C# app that I wrote to read from serial ports tells me "the parameter is incorrect".

EDIT:
sscanf is not the only function that doesn't work. I also need to have a CAN interface, and HAL_CAN_Receive() causes the same issues.
The above code is not my real project; it's just a simpler version that demonstrates the issue I'm having.

EDIT 2:
The above code works, but only if I run it without a debugger. In other words, If I flash the board, then plug it in, it works without issue. But if I run it through gdb via Eclipse, it does not.

Comment: Do any of the `#include`s bring in the declaration of `sscanf`?

Comment: If you disable interrupts while calling `sscanf`, does it then work in the debugger?

Comment: Your `sscanf(str,"%*s %d\r\n",&x);` has incorrect parameters. Maybe it stops working because the MCU gets an exception and halts?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this has been resolved or not but I've had the similar issue on one of the STM32 devices. Issue was not related to USB CDC or anything like that.

Issue was caused by sscanf(). After checking the library sources I've found out that sscanf() can allocate 10Kbytes+ on the stack. That on a device we were running code on would cause corruption in heap area of the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same issue. Code completely unrelated to the USB CDC would cause it to stop functioning, while the rest of the code worked fine.

Changing the binary parser in Eclipse, to "GNU Elf Parser", seems to have solved the problem. It was previously set to "Elf Parser".

Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers

I came across this, after having given up trying to diagnose my code (figure 5):
http://hertaville.com/using-the-eclipse-ide-gcc-arm.html

---

STM32Cube V1.0,
Version 4.24.0,
Microcontroller package STM32CubeFW_F4V1.19.0

System Workbench for STM32 - OpenOCD (for Windows 32bits),
Version: 1.13.2.201703061529

=====================================================================
Update:
Apologies, it turned out to be another red herring. USB Worked until the next time I had to change some code (not related to USB). Maybe ST should change their slogan from "life.Augmented" to "frustration.Augmented".

Update:
It appears that the problem was a CDC control request that was not being answered. The switch cases for control requests (in the ST example code) are all blank.
I added the code below in file: usbd_cdc_if.c, function CDC_Control_FS(). I have not had any more problems with random malfunctions.

```
static int8_t CDC_Control_FS(uint8_t cmd, uint8_t* pbuf, uint16_t length){
    ...
    case CDC_GET_LINE_CODING:
        // Called when usb cable is plugged in (no terminal program)
        // Called when terminal program connects
        pbuf[0] = 0x20; // bits/second 115200
        pbuf[1] = 0xc2;
        pbuf[2] = 0x01;
        pbuf[3] = 0x00;
        pbuf[4] = 0x00; // 1 stop bit
        pbuf[5] = 0x00; // parity none
        pbuf[6] = 0x08; // 8 data bits
        break;
    ...
}
```